# PHP save files to directory based on specific requirements

Tags: php

Sorry for (probably) kinda lame question, but i have been trying to figure this out for a kinda long time and for this, im too much of a beginner to solve this.

So i have a lot (hundreds) of excel files and im searching for a PHP script (or something else) that is able to move them into another directory.

**Example:**

> files XAA, XBB, XCC, XDD etc belong to folder X files YAA, YBB, YCC,
>   YDD etc belong to folder y

It would be great if PHP would be capable of doing this, for example like "if the name contains "X" move it to folder X". I believe and hope it is, its really pain in the ass to do it manually.

Thank you good people of internet for any kind of help.

Comment: "but i have been trying to figure this out for a kinda long time and for this, im too much of a beginner to solve this." show what you've done, how it failed

Comment: Loop through your files, and then use something like [`rename($file, "{$dir}/$file")`](http://php.net/rename). You'll need to get the first character of each file name which can be done through [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr) -> `rename($file, substr($file, 0, 1) . "/" . $file);`. (*Obviously making sure all directories exist,etc...*)

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche - well, pretty much, nothing. I have been searching internet to find something but i have failed.

Comment: @Darren thanks i will try it, but dont i have to define "rules"? Like files named X goes to folder X? Thanks

Comment: Nope, provided your files are named the same, you only ever need to know the first letter!

Comment: @Eddy stop searching to find something you can copy and paste, learn the basics of the tool you have chosen to do the job. This is fairly trivial.